# Error inside visual studio 2022 Comunity 17.5.34

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor, maui

I created a new MAUI Blazor project and this is what i end up with. Didn't touch anything, this is out of the box project! Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing and opening VS? Very often that helps.

Comment: I tried to [install Maui module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin#installation-1) via visual installer and it mentioned I need to install the module like screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZptD.png   But I met the same error with yours, so I installed all the modules related to `Desktop & Mobile` app, then I created the blazor maui app successfully. I recommend you taking a try to install all of them.

Comment: Focus on the warning triangle.  Open the Dependencies node to find out what is missing.

Comment: Have this happened before? or just happen after you update Visual Studio?

Comment: It happened after update. I use preview version 17.6 Preview 2.0 (latest at this point)

Comment: You could check if all workloads have been installed. [dotnet workload command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload). You could also try using Visual Studio Installer to modify.

Comment: I guess it was a IDE issue. When i openned the project a few days later everything just worked. It is true that i ran dotnet workload command and then never opened the project again until a few days later. So.. solved i guess